# Is spring getbean case sentitive or not?

Tags: java, spring

when I use `getBean("test")`

I have a class like

```
@Component
public class TEST {
}
```

can this bean be loaded?

Comment: Have you tried load bean like this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`getBean()` **is** case sensitive, however Spring uses custom bean naming strategy for `@Component` and `@Bean` classes. See [*4.10.5 Naming autodetected components*](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-scanning-name-generator):

> When a component is autodetected as part of the scanning process, its bean name is generated by the `BeanNameGenerator` strategy [...]. By default, any Spring stereotype annotation (`@Component`, `@Repository`, `@Service`, and `@Controller`) that contains a `name` value will thereby provide that name to the corresponding bean definition.
>
> If such an annotation contains no `name` value or for any other detected component (such as those discovered by custom filters), the **default bean name generator returns the uncapitalized non-qualified class name**.

And for `@Configuration`/`@Bean` see [*4.12.4.5 Customizing bean naming*](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-customizing-bean-naming):

> By default, configuration classes use a `@Bean` method's name as the name of the resulting bean. This functionality can be overridden, however, with the `name` attribute.

Back to your question. Because your class is not following Java naming conventions (camel-case names) Spring uses unusual name for the bean, this will work:

```
getBean("TEST")
```

However if you use expected naming (`@Component class Test { }`), you must use lower-case identifiers:

```
getBean("test")
```

Moreover if your name is more complex, uncapitalized camel-case syntax applies (continuing to quote the [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-scanning-name-generator)):

> [...] For example, if the following two components were detected, the names would be `myMovieLister` and `movieFinderImpl`:

```
@Service("myMovieLister")
public class SimpleMovieLister {
  // ...
}

@Repository
public class MovieFinderImpl implements MovieFinder {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tomasz. It is more complex than my expectation. If my class is something like @Component class TestTree, can I use getBean("testTree") to load it?

Comment: @user496949: exactly. Actually it isn't complex. You would probably use the same name for a variable holding a class of type `TestTree`. Moreover you should use statically typed `getBean(TestTree.class)` nowadays

Answer (score 12):

`@Component` annotation uses `AnnotationBeanNameGenerator` by default which, if not explicitly given a name, will use `Introspector.decapitalize()` method on the bean ClassName to get a name for the bean. Normally a class with name like "Test" will give it bean name "test". But `decapitalize` has a curiosity:

> This normally means converting the first character from upper case to
>   lower case, but in the (unusual) special case when there is more than
>   one character and both the first and second characters are upper case,
>   we leave it alone.

So your `class TEST` will get bean name `TEST`.