# Spring - proper way to use @Component annotated class in Main

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I have my `TCPServer` class implementing `Runnable` and annotated with `@Component`.
And I have a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` which will run the `TCPServer`.

In `TCPServer` I also have a class which is annotated with `@Repository`.
If I try to call `taskExecutor.execute(new TCPServer())` this will not be managed by Spring so my repository object will be null.

How can I get an instance of `TCPServer` in `Main` so I can give it to taskExecutor?

TCPServer:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class TCPServer implements Runnable {

  @Autowired
  private StudentRepository studentRepository;
  //rest of code
}
```

StudentRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, Long> {

}
```

I already tried like this:

```
TCPServer tcpServer = (TCPServer) applicationContext.getBean("tcpServer");
```

But this is what I got:

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'tcpServer' available

**Edit:**

`MySpringApplication`: *com.example.myspringapp;*

`TCPServer`: *com.example.myspringapp.server;*

Comment: Maybe it's just a naming issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967279/is-spring-getbean-case-sentitive-or-not Have you tried naming your class 'TcpServer' and recovering it with the last line you pointed?

Comment: Getting the bean using `applicationContext.getBean("tcpServer")` is correct. Probably the bean `TCPServer` was not created. I suspect that it's not in a sub-package of the main class package. Can you add the packages of the main applciation class and TCPServer class.

Comment: Also try betting the bean by type `TCPServer tcpServer = (TCPServer) applicationContext.getBean(TCPServer.class);`

Comment: Edited my post and added the packages for the two classes. Also trying to get the bean by type gives the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the class is called `TCPServer`, the bean name will be `TCPServer` (apparently Spring doesn't lowercase the first character, if the class name starts with a sequence of uppercase characters). For the bean name `tcpServer`, the class name has to be `TcpServer`.

Alternatively, you can specify the bean name in the Component annotation:

```
@Component("tcpServer")
```

For getting the bean by type, you have to use the correct type. If your class implements an interface and you didn't specify

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
```

on your main configuration class, Spring will use default JDK proxies to create the beans, which implement then the interfaces of the class and don't extend the class itself. So the bean type of `TCPServer` in your case is `Runnable.class` and not `TCPServer.class`.

So either use bean names to get the bean or add the proxy annotation to use the class as type.

Comment: `TCPServer tcpServer = applicationContext.getBean(TCPServer.class); `This gives the same result

Comment: Yes, because your class implements an interface. Then the type of your bean is the interface, if you didn't specify the correct proxying mode. Will edit that into my answer.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks for the help and for the explanation. Didn't knew that until now.